# Доработать скрипт

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы этот скрипт не выдавал alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!"), когда введено 2 и более слов.

```js
var lastResFind=""; // последний удачный результат
var copy_page=""; // копия страницы в ихсодном виде
function TrimStr(s) {
     s = s.replace( /^\s+/g, '');
  return s.replace( /\s+$/g, '');
}
function FindOnPage(inputId) {//ищет текст на странице, в параметр передается ID поля для ввода
  var obj = window.document.getElementById(inputId);
  var textToFind;
 
  if (obj) {//проверка на существование элемента
    textToFind = TrimStr(obj.value);//обрезаем пробелы
  } else {
    alert("Введенная фраза не найдена");
    return;
  }
  if (textToFind == "") {
    alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
    return;
  }
  if (textToFind.length < 2 ) {
    alert("Поиск не может быть настолько коротким. Пожалуйста, введите значение длиннее 1 символа");
    return;
  }

 if( !/[A-Z]/i.test(textToFind)) //проверка на наличие латиницы и запросов, "ломающих" стиль страницы
  {
    if(/[а-яА-Я]/i.test(textToFind)){
      //все хорошо  - пускаем дальше
    }
  else{alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!");
    return;}
  }
  else{alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!");
    return;}



  if(copy_page.length>0)
        document.body.innerHTML=copy_page;
  else copy_page=document.body.innerHTML;

  
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name="+lastResFind+"/gi")," ");//стираем предыдущие якори для скрола
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/"+textToFind+"/gi"),"<a name="+textToFind+" style='border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0000; padding-top: 100px; font-size:15px'>"+textToFind+"</a>")//Заменяем найденный текст ссылками с якорем;
  if(document.getElementsByName(textToFind).length == "0"){
  alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!");
    return;
  }
  lastResFind=textToFind; // сохраняем фразу для поиска, чтобы в дальнейшем по ней стереть все ссылки
  window.location = '#'+textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению
 }
```

Comment: Добавьте в код разметку чтоб можно было воспроизвести ваш пример.

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед,если есть функция trim?Латиница ломает страницу?))Лучше проверили бы на \d.Использовать eval?По поводу чтобы не выдавал сообщение...так по вашей логике,все хорошо это когда кириллица с цифрами